# mongodb replication cannot add secondary replica

Tags: mongodb, configuration, replication

I have configured the replica set with primary and 2 secondary nodes,  did managed to add one secondary to primary and can see the replication works not am trying to add the 2 secondary and  get errors like " Failed to execute "list databases" command when manually connect using the robot 3T directly inside the server and when see in the replica set it says an error stateStr as "not reachable/health"

Primary server : created replica set
Secondary server : Assigned the replica set name
Secondary Server : Assigned the replica set name
Primary Server : rs.initiate , rs.add("Secondary Server")
but in one of the secondary server i get an error cannot list databases

Comment: Error "not reachable/health" is quite obvious. Either the service is not started or connection is blocked by firewall. What are the config files of the servers?

Comment: mongodb service is running , i added the port to inbound and outbound in the firewall flow, In config file , port 20717 , bindIp: ServerIP, replication : replSetName : Narsing (narsing is the replica set created and working with one primary and one secondary)

Comment: Can you try to reach the host with curl: `curl --connect-timeout 10 --silent --show-error ServerIP:27017` Response should be "*It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.*"

Comment: I fixed the issues, the issue was related to the data files at the instance level, i deleted the data files and re-added the member to primary server and now it works fine